# A question about analystic function $ f$defined in a Angular domain.We want to show $f =0$ by adding some extra condition.$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Problem:let$G=\{z:0＜argz＜{π\over4}\}$. $f$ is analytic on $G$ while is continuous on $\bar G$. If $f=0$ on interval $[a,b]$ lining in the real axis,show that f equals 0 on G.

My attempt:I never see that condition (f is continuous on $\bar G$) Generally,I only see condition thatf is analytic in a open set and curve lies in $G$ in my books.
My idea is use the uniqueness of analytic function on a region. But I have not concret resort to approach this idal.

Comment: Using the Schwarz reflection principle along $(a,b)$ and Morera theorem to show that the obtained extension is analytic. Otherwise you can multiply $f$ with some rotated versions of it to get a function $g$ analytic on $U$ continuous on $U\cup \partial U$ and vanishing on $\partial U$ so the maximum modulus principle gives $g=0$.

Comment: I am so sorry because I can't understand your idea.

Comment: So far,I don't know Schwarz reflection principle.In fact,this problem only appears after Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: My hint is pretty clear, multiply $f$ with things like $f(iz)$ to get that the boundary curve where it vanishes encloses a region. You can conclude with the Cauchy integral formula if you want to.